# I want to create bold and normal text in my pdf

Tags: python, reportlab

I can create pdf file from a txt file with reportlab. This is easy but I want to do some text is bold, some is normal, some is italic. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

There's some good insight in [their documentation](http://www.reportlab.com/software/opensource/rl-toolkit/faq/#2.1.4). Roughly, the bold and italic versions of any font are actually distinct fonts. So you just set the font when you want to change fonts. 
This could probably be tightened up but worked for me:

```
import reportlab
import os
from reportlab.pdfgen import canvas
from reportlab.pdfbase import pdfmetrics 
from reportlab.pdfbase.ttfonts import TTFont  

canv = canvas.Canvas("fonts_demo.pdf")

font_variants = ("DejaVuSans","DejaVuSans-Oblique","DejaVuSans-Bold")
folder = '/usr/share/fonts/truetype/dejavu/'
for variant in font_variants:
    pdfmetrics.registerFont(TTFont(variant, os.path.join(folder, variant+'.ttf'))) 

""" I could have registered each font with a line like this... 
pdfmetrics.registerFont(TTFont(DejaVuSans, os.path.join(folder,'DejaVuSans.ttf')))
but I like just making a list of my fonts and then iterating through it. """

## 0,0 is the bottom left corner of the page
## and there are 72 dots per inch, so on an 8.5 inch page
## the top left corner is at 8.5 * 72
## canvas actually generates an A4 sheet, but this is close enough.
x = 0; y = 8.5 * 72
canv.setFont('DejaVuSans-Bold', 30) 
canv.drawString(x,y,"This is bold")

## Move down one inch to draw the next line:
y = y - 72 
canv.setFont('DejaVuSans-Oblique', 30) 
canv.drawString(x,y,"This is oblique, aka italic")


## Move down one inch again:
y = y - 72
canv.setFont('DejaVuSans', 30) 
canv.drawString(x,y,"This is neither bold nor italic")

## Save your work
canv.save()
```

Comment: PS. Technically "oblique" and "italic" are different. But that's a whole other question/can of worms